# AVL Trees and Doubly Linked Lists

Tags: c++, list, c++11

so, I am really new to programming, and I am taking a c++ class right now, in which I need to write and implement and AVL Tree, using a Doubly Linked lists to print off the contents of my tree, level by level. The teacher is really picky, so we can't use any containers from the standard libraries. My Doubly Linked list should be working fine, because I used it on a previous project, but I am getting an error when trying to combine it with the AVL Tree. I know my code probably has A LOT of things that need to be modified, but one step at a time. I am getting the following error, so I was wondering if you guys could help me figure out how to fix it. Also, if you have any suggestions on how to better my code, I would appreciate it.

In instantiation of ‘void AVLTreeSet::print(std::ofstream&) [with ItemType = std::basic_string; std::ofstream = std::basic_ofstream]’:
Lab6/main.cpp:80:20:   required from here
Lab6/AVLTreeSet.h:152:49: error: cannot convert ‘LinkedList >::AVLNode*>::Node*’ to ‘AVLTreeSet >::AVLNode*’ in initialization
                     AVLNode* n = MyList.remove(i);

This is my AVLTree.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
#include "LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

template <typename ItemType>

class AVLTreeSet {


    struct AVLNode {
        ItemType item;
        int height;
        AVLNode* left;
        AVLNode* right;

        AVLNode(const ItemType& _item, AVLNode* _left = NULL, AVLNode* _right = NULL, int _height = 0) :
                item(_item), left(_left), right(_right), height(_height) {}
    };


    AVLNode* root;
    int size = 0;


public:
    void RemoveBelowRoot(AVLNode *& n, const ItemType& item)
    {
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if(item < n->item)
        {
            RemoveBelowRoot(n->left, item);
        }
        else if(item > n->item)
        {
            RemoveBelowRoot(n->right, item);
        }
        else if(n->left == NULL)
        {
            n = n->right;
        }
        else if (n->right == NULL)
        {
            n = n->left;
        }
        else
        {
            n = findMin(n->right);
            RemoveBelowRoot(n->right, n->item);
        }
        balance(n);
        size--;
        // update height of nodes on this path
    }

    AVLNode * findMin(AVLNode* n)
    {
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return n;
        }
        else if (n->left->item < n->item)
        {
            findMin(n->left);
        }
        else if(n->left->item > n->item)
        {
            findMin(n->right);
        }
        return n;
    }
    void remove(const ItemType& item) {

        RemoveBelowRoot(root, item);

    }

    bool find(const ItemType& item) {

        if (findBelowRoot(root, item))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
    bool findBelowRoot(AVLNode * n, const ItemType& data)
    {
        if (n->item == data)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (data > n->item)
        {
            findBelowRoot(n->right, data);
        }
        else if (data < n->item)
        {
            findBelowRoot(n->left, data);
        }
    }
    void clear()
    {
        while (getHeight(root) != 0)
        {
            // remove
        }
    }

    void addBelowRoot(AVLNode *& n, const ItemType& item)
    {
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            n = new AVLNode(item);
            size++;
        }
        else if (item < n->item)
        {
            addBelowRoot(n->left, item);
        }
        else if(item > n->item)
        {
            addBelowRoot(n->right, item);
        }


    }
    void add(const ItemType& item) {

        addBelowRoot(root, item);

    }
    void print (ofstream& out)
    {
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        else {
            LinkedList<AVLNode *> MyList;
            MyList.insert(0, root); // add root to Q
            while (MyList.getSize() != 0) // While Q is not empty
                //(figure out how many items are in that level)(levelsize = Q.size();)
            {
                for (auto i = 0; i < MyList.getSize(); i++) // for (int 1 = 0; i < LEVELSIZE; i++)
                {
                    AVLNode* n = MyList.remove(i);
                    out << "level " << i << " " << n->item << "(" << n->height << ") ";
                    if (n->left != NULL) {
                        MyList.insert(MyList.getSize(), n->left);
                    }
                    if (n->right != NULL) {
                        MyList.insert(MyList.getSize(), n->right);
                    }
                }
            }
            out << "\n ";
        }
    }

    void balance (AVLNode *n)
    {
        if (getHeight(n->left) - getHeight(n->right))
        {
            balanceToRight(n);
        }
        if (getHeight(n->right) - getHeight(n->left))
        {
            balanceToLeft(n);
        }
    }
    int getHeight(AVLNode *& n)
    {
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return n->height;
        }
    }
    void balanceToRight(AVLNode * n)
    {
        if (getHeight(n->left->right) > getHeight(n->left->left))
        {
            rotateLeft(n->left);
        }
        rotateRight(n);
    }
    void rotateRight(AVLNode *&n)
    {
        AVLNode * k = n->left;
        n->left = k->right;
        k->right = n;
        n = k;
        // update heights of k and n
    }
    void rotateLeft(AVLNode *& n)
    {
        AVLNode * k = n->right;
        n->right = k->left;
        k->left = n;
        n = k;
        // update heights of k and n
    }
    void balanceToLeft(AVLNode * n)
    {
        if (getHeight(n->right->left) > getHeight(n->right->right)) // check with TAs if this is right
        {
            rotateRight(n);
        }
            rotateLeft(n);

    }
    /*void updateHeight(AVLNode *& n)
    {

    }*/


};
```

Now this is my LinkedList.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

template <typename ItemType>

class LinkedList {


    struct Node {
        ItemType item;
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;

        Node(const ItemType &_item, Node *_next = NULL, Node *_prev = NULL) :
                item(_item), next(_next), prev(_prev) { }
    };


    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int size = 0;

public:

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        clear();
    }
    void insert(int index, ItemType& item) {

        if (index > size || size < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        Node * newNode = new Node(item);

        if (size == 0)
        {

            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
            newNode->next = NULL;
            newNode->prev = NULL;
            size++;
        }

        else if (index == 0)
        {
            head->prev = newNode;
            newNode->next = head;
            head = newNode;
            size++;

        }
        else if (index == size) //INSERTING AT THE END
        {
            newNode->prev = tail;
            newNode->next = NULL;
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
            size++;

        }
        else {
            Node* n = find_node(index);
            newNode->next = n;
            newNode->prev = n->prev;
            n->prev->next = newNode;
            n->prev = newNode;
            size++;
        }


    }

    Node * remove(int index) {

        if (head == NULL || index >= size || index < 0)
        {
           return NULL;
        }
        else {
            Node* name = find_node(index);
            Node * n;
            if (size == 1) // REMOVE THE ONLY NODE
            {
                n = head;
                head = NULL;
                tail = NULL;
                size--;

            }
            else if (index == 0) //REMOVE THE FIRST NODE WHEN THERE'S MORE THAN ONE IN THE LIST
            {
                n = head;
                head = head->next;
                head->prev = NULL;
                size--;


            }
            else if (index == size-1) //REMOVE THE LAST WHEN THERE'S MORE THAN ONE NODE IN THE LIST
            {
                n = tail;
                tail = n->prev;
                tail->next = NULL;
                size--;

            }
            else
            {
                n = find_node(index);
                n->prev->next = n->next;
                n->next->prev = n->prev;
                size--;
            }

            delete n;
            return name;
        }
    }

    Node * find_node(int index)
    {
        Node * n = NULL;

        if (0 <= index && index <= size/2)
        {
            n = head;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                n = n->next;
            }
        }
        else if (size/2 < index && index <= size-1)
        {
            n = tail;

            for (unsigned i = size-1; i > index; i--)
            {
                n = n->prev;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
    int getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }
/*    void print(LinkedList <string>& list, ofstream& out, int i)
    {
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }

        out << "node " << i << ": " << getItem(i) << "\n";
    }

    Node* getItem(const int index)
    {
        if (index > size)
        {
            return  NULL;
        }
        Node* temp = head;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (i == index)
            {
                return temp;
            }
            temp = temp-> next;
        }
        return NULL;

    }*/

/*    int find(const ItemType& item) {

        Node * NodeP = head;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (NodeP->item == item)
            {
                return i;
            }
            NodeP = NodeP->next;
        }
        return -1;

    }*/
    void clear()
    {
        while (size != 0){
            remove(0);
        }
    }

};
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Speak with your teacher regarding STL... That sounds miserable to be without it... Also, is there any relevant code in your main class?

Comment: The question should not be asking to through all your code. You should isolate the part of the program causing problem to get help.

Answer (score 2):

`LinkedList::remove` returns a `LinkedList::Node` pointer. You are trying to assign that into an `AVLTreeSet::AVLNode` pointer.

The `AVLTreeSet::AVLNode *` you are looking for is in the `item` member of the returned `Node` pointer.

You could do something like:

```
LinkedList<AVLNode *>::Node* n = MyList.remove(i);
AVLNode *treeNode = n->item;
```

Notes

- You should be checking for NULL as the return value for `remove`, if it doesn't find anything.
- `remove` actually `delete`s the node then returns it. You are then accessing something that has been deleted, which is Undefined Behavior. You **really** need to fix this before you go much further.
- your `for` loop will only remove about half of the objects, as your are removing items from the list while still iterating further along the list using `i`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was able to fix the part that was giving me trouble.
So, about Note #2, would you recommend that I create a function getNode inside my LinkedList.h that returns a Node*, and then call the remove function?

Comment: You already have `find_node` which does this. You could just make `remove_node` into a void function, or perhaps return true or false to indicate whether an item was removed. You would have to change your caller, but not by much.